# random string generator in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 1 file: testController.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$Quantity = 5;
$Promo_code = Str::random($length = 10);
   for($i = 0; $i < $Quantity; $i++){
      \Debugbar::info($Promo_code);
   }
```

result:

```
a366PPbdB6

a366PPbdB6

a366PPbdB6

a366PPbdB6

a366PPbdB6

a366PPbdB6
```

I want the result to be random code
For example:

```
rxXELTrs9z

BOja7WVDHl

6NWL91Den1

GxAdiVHuIV

Lyaf9GPwn9
```

thanks you for help me!

Comment: Put the line `$Promo_code = Str::random($length = 10);` inside the loop.

Comment: This is random but unique. Shouldn't the promo code be unique also?

Answer (score 4):

You are generating random string outside of the loop. Therefore in every loop, you are passing the same (the only generated) one to `info()` method. Try moving it inside in order to generate in every cycle:

```
$Quantity = 5;

for($i = 0; $i < $Quantity; $i++){
   $Promo_code = Str::random($length = 10);
   \Debugbar::info($Promo_code);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You rand once and use many times.

Just move `$Promo_code = Str::random($length = 10);` into `for` loop will works.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass the promo code variable inside the loop such as

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$Quantity = 5;
for($i = 0; $i < $Quantity; $i++){
   $Promo_code = Str::random($length = 10);
   \Debugbar::info($Promo_code);
}
```